# Can't install node packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am trying to install the node packages using 'npm install' but when ever I do it I get only errors?

`Error Codes Here` https://pastebin.com/39mC3nPm

`Log Here` https://pastebin.com/7PtCPdpX

Hope someone can help, Thanks!

Comment: Please include the error message and relevant log entries in your question.

Comment: try `npm rebuild node-sass` then an `npm install` again

Comment: Tried it @Rick, Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states:

> Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

so my guess is you have to install Python 2.7 in order for this to work.

In case you still get error, I see you are using Windows, there are known issues with node-sass missing versions for Windows, for example see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1817) or [its issue tracker](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues) for more information.

Comment: I tried installing python and yes it has fixed a lot of errors but there are some still left that I still get this:

'Build Failed:' https://pastebin.com/wSc28xKP

Comment: `MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Fram ework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it  is installed elsewhere.`